# how to order an active record query by existence of a table entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have submissions that I would like to order by whether or not the user has seen it, and if the user has seen it, then by the number of views it has (in ascending order).  This way, the user will be able to see new submissions on next page/refresh, while not completely removing viewed submissions from sight.  I currently have 2 tables: submissions and views.

```
submissions
-----------
user_id
story_id
body

views
-----------
user_id
submissions_id
```

I have a query that orders by number of views:

```
@story.submissions.select("submissions.*, count(views.submission_id) as views_count").
      joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN views on views.submission_id=submissions.id").
      group("submissions.id").
      order("views_count")
```

But I'm unsure how to order by whether or not there is an entry in the views table.

**EDIT**
The query i had wasn't working, even though it did work once.

Comment: What should the order be if the user hasn't seen it; still sorted by popularity?

Comment: By number of views, in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
@story.submissions.select("submissions.*, count(views.submission_id) as views_count, user_views.id as user_view_id").
       joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN views on views.submission_id=submissions.id LEFT OUTER JOIN views as user_views on user_views.submission_id=submissions.id and user_views.user_id = #{current_user.id}").
       group("submissions.id").
       order("user_view_id ASC, views_count DESC")
```

The idea being that `user_view_id` will be null if the user hasn't seen the post and non-null otherwise.